# How to determine whether to use join in linq to sql?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, join

I am just wondering about how we can determine whether to use `join` or not in `linq to sql`.

Eg. let say if we have two tables like this

```
Table 1   Customer
          id
          name

Table 2   addresstype
          id
          address1
          customerid
```

and

```
var address = from cu in Customer
              from ad in addresstype
              where cu.id == ad.customerid
              select ad;
```

or

```
var address = from cu in Customer
              join ad in addresstype on cu.id equals ad.customerid
              select de;
```

Is both way are the same. Is there any difference in performance?

Also the second method, will it come up with an error if there isn’t any matching?

Comment: The second method won't error if there are none matching... It'll produce no results, like te equivalent SQL query would

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, these two LINQ queries are equivalent to the following SQL queries:

```
 select ad.*
 from Customer cu, AddressType ad
 where cu.ID == ad.CustomerID -- I assume this was meant by the OP
```

and

```
select ad.*
from Customer cu
  inner join AddressType ad on cu.id = ad.CustomerID;
```

The difference between these two queries is mostly semantic, since the database will do the same thing in both cases and return a same result set for both queries.

I would prefer the `join` syntax in both SQL and LINQ since it defines an explicit relationship between the two tables/entities, that is only implied in the join-less version.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using linq to entities or linq to SQL? If its the former then you can avoid both of these by defining your relationships in the model and using navigation properties. This would be the clearest way of doing things

Comment: Well you cant use my suggestion :) maybe consider linq to entities next time!

Comment: LINQ to SQL supports associations which are the same as EF's navigation properties.

Answer (score 1):

These are seems same query, they return same result but I don't know which one can be a faster, it should be bench marked.

But, In the case of `linq2sql` I prefer correlated subquery over join, because currently if you want t check the equation two element you should use syntax of:

```
new {X,Y} equals new {X',Y'}
```

in join and if you have more than this equations you should convert it to nested query. So I Prefer to have a more readable code which uses minimum differences in difference actions.

Answer (score 1):

To throw a third and more prefered method into the mix with LINQ to SQL, use associations between the tables (even if you don't have them set up in your database). With that in place, you can navigate the object graph rather than using joins:

```
var query = from cu in Customer 
              from ad in cu.Addresses 
              select ad;
```

Note: when querying the object graphs, LINQ to SQL translates the join into a left outer join where-as the join/where syntax by default is an inner join.

Joins in LINQ should be used when there isn't a natural relationship between the objects. For example, use a join if you want to see the the listing of stores that are in the same city as your customers. (Join Customer.Address.City with Store.Address.City).

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a difference between these two queries. I actually wondered this question myself a few months ago. I verified this through LINQPad. It's a free tool that you can download and actually see the generated SQL of any LINQ query (this is the query that is sent to the database).

The generated SQL should be the same for these two queries.

If you're doing this through Visual Studio, there is also a way you can see the generated SQL as well.

Comment: FYI, for LINQ to SQL to see the generated SQL, just call .ToString on the query.